# How to make one drawing follow the other (html canvas)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have two drawings: one arc and one circle and I want the circle to follow the end of the arc. Basically, i need to fetch the x&y of the `endAngle` of the arc so I would use it on the circle to follow it.

```
 //Arc
 context.beginPath(); 
 var x2 = canvas.width / 2; 
 var y2 = canvas.height / 2; 
 var radius2 = 215; 
 var startAngle2 = 1.5 * Math.PI; 
 var endAngle2= 2.3 * Math.PI; 
 var counterClockwise2 = false; 
 context.arc(x2, y2, radius2, startAngle2, endAngle2, counterClockwise2); 
 context.lineWidth = 10; 
 context.strokeStyle = "blue"; 
 context.stroke(); 

 //Circle
 context.beginPath(); 
 var x3 = x2+ 130; 
 var y3 = y2 + 200; 
 var radius3 = 20; 
 var startAngle3 = 0 * Math.PI; 
 var endAngle3 = 2 * Math.PI; 
 var counterClockwise3 = false; 
 context.arc(x3, y3, radius3, startAngle3, endAngle3, counterClockwise3); 
 context.lineWidth = 5; 
 context.strokeStyle = "yellow"; 
 context.stroke();
```

Comment: Do you want to do it tangential? you need some math, their `lineWidth`s are different though

Comment: It'll be easier if you draw what you want with `paint` for instance and upload it as an image

Comment: I will animate the arc with the timer so the endPoint() will move. I would like the x,y of the circle to follow that x,y. Is paint a method?

Comment: No, it's not, that was just for the purpose of explaining but I got you now. I think you want both the arc and the small yellow circle to turn around the black circle, right?

Comment: Yes that is right! They will be moving together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the x,y coordinates of the end of the arc, you should work with `cos` for x and `sin` for y.

Get the end of your arc (x,y) like so:

```
var x3 = canvas.width / 2 + radius2*Math.cos(endAngle2);
var y3 = canvas.height / 2  + radius2*Math.sin(endAngle2);
```

Comment: @Kostis, How does my solution work? I think it's better than this one since it uses a built-in function that handle the calculation for you and make it more precise

Comment: I had a go with it but still i can't get the endAngle of the element to automatically move the other element.

Comment: @Kostis in my solution, your `endAngle` stays fixed, the angle you provide to `ctx.rotate()` will rotate the whole arc and circle together, you can play with it

Comment: Yes you are right, it works exactly like that. My intention though is to animate the endAngle point for a certain time so it seems that it grows larger over time and the circle will follow it.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use [`ctx.rotate(angle);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)
The center of the rotation is the origin of the canvas identified by 0,0. In order to choose another one you need to use [`ctx.translate(x, y);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) where x,y are the coordinates of the center of the rotation hence

```
context.translate(x1,y1)
context.rotate(20*Math.PI/180)
```

Finally, you need to change your coordinates to refer to the new center

```
    context.arc(x2, y2, radius2, startAngle2, endAngle2, counterClockwise2);
...

....

    var x3 = x2 + 130;
    var y3 = y2 + 200;
```

becomes

```
context.arc(0, 0, radius2, startAngle2, endAngle2, counterClockwise2);
....

...
var x3 =  130;
var y3 =  200;
```

**Here's the full code:**

```js
   var canvas=document.getElementById("clock");
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


context.beginPath();

      var x1 = canvas.width/2;
      var y1 = canvas.height/2;
      var radius1 = 200;
      var startAngle1 = 0 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle1 = 2 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise1 = false;

context.arc(x1, y1, radius1, startAngle1, endAngle1, counterClockwise1);
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
context.font = "bold 76px Arial";
context.textAlign="center"; 
context.textBaseline="middle"; 
context.fillText("25:00", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

 
context.beginPath();

context.translate(x1,y1)
context.rotate(Math.PI)
var radius2 = 215;
var startAngle2 = 1.5 * Math.PI;
var endAngle2 = 2.3 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise2 = false;
context.arc(0, 0, radius2, startAngle2, endAngle2, counterClockwise2);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
var x3 = 130;
var y3 = 200;
var radius3 = 20;
var startAngle3 = 0 * Math.PI;
var endAngle3 = 2 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise3 = false;
context.arc(x3, y3, radius3, startAngle3, endAngle3, counterClockwise3);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
context.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #50B3B9;
}

#clock {
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
}

#time {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}


----------
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="clock" width="600" height="600">
      <div id="time">25:00</div>
    </canvas>
  </div>
```